# Why does this code throw Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space?

Tags: java

```java
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;

public class ComputeIfAbsentWithHashSetNew {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var map = new HashMap<Integer, HashSet<Integer>>();
        var data = new int[][]{{305589003, 4136}, {305589004, 4139}};
        for (var entry : data) {
            int x = entry[0];
            int y = entry[1];
//            map.computeIfAbsent(x, _x -> new HashSet<>()).add(y); // ----- line 1
            var k = map.computeIfAbsent(x, HashSet::new);           // ----- line 2
            k.add(y);
        }
    }
}
```

Above code throws at jdk 17、 18、 19:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.resize(HashMap.java:702)
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.putVal(HashMap.java:627)
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:610)
    at java.base/java.util.HashSet.add(HashSet.java:221)
    at _explore.ComputeIfAbsentWithHashSetNew.main(ComputeIfAbsentWithHashSetNew.java:15)
```

When debug, I see the `newCap` in `Hashmap::resize()` is very large, I don't know why. I thought both the lines do same thing previously.

When I replace **line 2** with **line 1** in code, it runs successfully.

Comment: *"When I replace line 2 with line 1 in code, it runs successfully."* because they do completely different things. One creates an `HashSet` with default capacity, the other creates an `HashSet` with initial capacity `x`, which may very well be 305589003, which is rather big.

Comment: `computeIfAbsent` calls the 2nd parameter (a `Function`) with the key as argument, in this case `305589003`; the passed function `HashSet::new` is the `HashSet(int initialCapacity)` - as commented above, `305589003` as capacity is too big to be stored in the available memory (line 1 should be `k -> new HashSet<>(k)` to be the same as line 2, both wrong)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`HashSet::new` is a method reference pointing to `new HashSet(initialCapacity)`. See the  java-doc of [HashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#HashSet(int)).

So, it creates a bigger `HashSet`s than you expect, because it takes your `x` variable as parameter.

Comment: a detail: `HashSet::new` is not a lambda but just a method reference (according JLS [15.27. Lambda Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se19/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27))